# button not showing inside a drawer

Tags: android

i defined a drawer that works fine, but when i' ve added a button this one is not shown, and i don't understand why.

***I want this button to stay at the bottom of the list view.***

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer_for_boundary"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#123456"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_for_radius"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:text="@string/set_radius"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:max="5"
            android:progress="0" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/right_boundary_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="#123456"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_boundary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/confirm_boundary" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

naturally i get the button via `setButton((Button) findViewById(R.id.button_boundary));`

so why is it not showing?

Comment: this is coz your list is covering the whole area of drawer and hiding the button.

Comment: @SuhailMehta well, thanks for the comment, i suspected this, and now you confirmed. How i can add the button on the bottom, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Suhail Mehta said, your ListView is covering the button, just change your code to this:

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/right_boundary_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#123456"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp" />
```

The weight property will tell the `ListView` to take all remaining space on the screen but without covering any other widget

Answer (score 2):

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/right_boundary_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:background="#123456"
            android:layout_weight= "1"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="5dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use the `RelativeLayout`.

Example xml code would be something like:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer_for_boundary"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#123456"
        android:visibility="visible" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_boundary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:alignParentBottom="true"
                android:text="@string/confirm_boundary" />
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_below="@id/button_boundary"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
                <!-- TextView, SeekBar and ListView here -->
            </LinearLayout> 
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Hope it helps.